# Flex Storing Variable

Tags: apache-flex

I am new in flex development so I need a help to understand logic and solution for my requirement,
My Concern is when I login to particular page i want to stored a navigation menu name in any variable or any collection so I can check my last visited page name by that variable or collection data.
Is there any possibility where I check what was my last page visited.
I have a requirement like this to handle refresh event in flex pages.
when I refresh my page I want to go back to same page
your valuable comments and your knowledge is needed.

Comment: Do you need a breadcrumb?

Comment: Breadcrumb will be a good idea ...

Comment: RIA Dev will you please share and sample code where i can get that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to create a NavigationManager class where you can store in static variables the informations you need.

For example

```
class MyNavigationManager
{

    private static var _visitedPages:Array = [];

    public static function pushPage(pageName:String):void
    {
        _visitedPages.push(pageName);
    }

    public static function get currentPageName():String
    {
        if(_visitedPages.length > 0 )
             return _visitedPages[_visitedPages.length -1 ];

        return null;
    }

    // ...something else you may need, maybe popPage():Sting...
}
```

And to use it you can call from any place in your app

```
MyNavigationManager.pushPage("Home");
MyNavigationManager.pushPage("User Account");
trace(MyNavigationManager.currentPageName);
```

**Update 1**

Since you need independent SharedObjects based on browser type (as requested in the comments...)

Get browser name

```
var userAgent : String  = String(ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.userAgent}"));
trace (userAgent);
```

Use userAgent to create different shared objects, and initialize like this.

```
public var sharedObj:SharedObject;

private function initSharedObject():void
{
    sharedObj = SharedObject.getLocal("SO_"+userAgent.subStr(0,6));
}
```

Hope that it is better now.

Comment: Thanks Adrian,But I need to implement that functionality on browser refresh and if i do browser refresh then MyNavigationManager.currentPageName will give me null value.

Comment: then your complete concept is wrong... try using flash sharedObjects to store your last 'session details' (shared objects are like cookies for flash). Then on browser reload, read the last saved location/view your app was using and navigate programatically to it..

Comment: Adrian I have one more question regarding flex session handling please give your valuable time to look into that...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196787/flex-session-handling-with-java   your valuable comments will help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Hi Adrian,As you said shared Objects are cookies for flex, I implement that in my application but as cookies are depend on the browser level so If i login my application in Mozilla and IE then its pointing to same share Object. is there any way where i can store share objects independently ,because of that If i refresh pages then its not navigate to same page,this issue i am facing right now, please need a help on that.

Comment: check Update1 in my answer

Comment: Hi Adrian, I made some changes as per your code but now if i log off from my application and re-login then it go back to previous page which was there before log off, I am clearing those shared Object when i am doing fresh login and and when i am doing log off. but still its showing strange behavior.Please give your valuable comments that will help me. thanks,

Comment: Hi Santosh, Could you please post parts of your code ? Would help a lot to understand what/how you are actually using the sahared objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function initSharedObject(userAgent:String):String
    {
        Alert.show("userAgent : "+userAgent+" substring : "+userAgent.substr(0,15));
        sharedObj = SharedObject.getLocal("SO_"+userAgent.substr(0,15));
        if (sharedObj.size > 0)
            var currentState:String =sharedObj.data.tasks;
        //Alert.show("curentState in init "+currentState);
        return currentState;
    }

    public function saveTasks(curentState:String):void {
        //Alert.show("curentState  "+curentState);
        sharedObj.data.tasks = curentState;
        sharedObj.flush();
    }

    public function deleteSavedTasks(userAgent:String):void {
        //Alert.show("Im in Delete ...");
        //Alert.show("userAgent : "+userAgent+" substring : "+userAgent.substr(0,11));
        sharedObj = SharedObject.getLocal("SO_"+userAgent.substr(0,15));
        sharedObj.clear();
    }
```

Hi Adrain ,
above code I am using in the share Objects handling in my application,But Sub String of userAgent String give me Output :

IE 11 : 
userAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; rv:11.0) like Gecko substring : Mozilla/5.0

Mozilla :
userAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 substring : Mozilla/5.0

Please check the above code and its substring output.
and please let me know.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I come up with one more question regarding SharedObject.. I implemented Shared Object in my application its working fine Thanks a lot for that help, But when I close a browser I am not able to delete a shared Object values.. Please give your valuable comments which will definitely help me resolve this issue. Thanks..