# Flex Session Handling with Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, session

I have implemented session handling in Flex Java application, But I am facing one issue in that.

When I login after that I am creating new flex session by :

```
session = FlexContext.getFlexSession();
```

But If I test my application in two different browser then :

•   IE browser : If  I login my application then its giving me  some session ID like (0704943129C2D91539D989EA1DB70D37).

•   Mozilla browser : If I login to my application at same time then its giving me a  different Session ID : (9073B8D787A7CDF0885A646B4BB8DBCC)

But in my application if I refresh browser then it should return to same page so I write a code  :

```
public String getCurrentState(){   

           System.out.println(session.getId());       
           return (String)session.getAttribute("currentState");
}
```

This method will give me current State of page so I can redirect to same page when I refresh my page.

when I run application in 2 different browser But in this method functionality of method will change automatically like:

IE Browser: if I am on ABC page and if I refresh browser it should go to same page like ABC same flow with Mozilla Browser.

But when I refresh my application in Mozilla then if IE having ABC and Mozilla showing XYZ then sometime it execute different like 
IE shows XYZ and Mozilla shows ABC.

I am confuse with this functionality.

Please kindly do needful help.

Thanks a lot for your HELP.

**Logs:**

PFA Below Logs For My Application :

IF I Login to IE Browser :

BBC5491525B53AD5473BFFF5DE811324
loginId before : admin0.09284337847701252
inside add Session :Id admin0.09284337847701252  sessionId BBC5491525B53AD5473BFFF5DE811324 loginType admin
loginId after : admin0.09284337847701252
status Written to Sessio

IF I login to Mozilla Browser :

B908B8B0F4E02D99A47DC4E276AC803B
loginId before : admin0.8330401328813781
inside add Session :Id admin0.8330401328813781  sessionId B908B8B0F4E02D99A47DC4E276AC803B loginType admin
loginId after : admin0.8330401328813781
status Written to Session

IF I refresh Mozilla Browser :

BBC5491525B53AD5473BFFF5DE811324

IF I refresh IE Browser :

B908B8B0F4E02D99A47DC4E276AC803B

Comment: I can't understand your problem. It is normal that if you visit the same page with two different browsers you start two different sessions. I think that this is why each browser uses a different session cookie.

Comment: If i host that application and try to access through different system then also its showing same behavior .. that's my issue..